# How can I provide tab completions to fish shell from my own script?

Tags: shell, autocomplete, tab-completion, fish

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 and fish 2.1.0. I want to write myself a Python script to do some tasks from the command line. The script will require command line arguments.

How can I write my script such that fish can request and get possible values for a given argument. The list of potential values is dynamic. That is, it will be determined programatically (e.g. a list of folder names matching some criteria).

The end result I am aiming for is something like:

```
user@machine ~> myprog argument=fol<TAB>
folder1  folder2  folder3
```

Where `myprog` is my script file, `argument` is the argument name and `folder1` etc are valid values generated by some function in my script.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: you should create a fish autocomplete function for your script (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657803/creating-autocomplete-script-with-sub-commands)

Comment: @furins so tab-completion can only be provided by writing an additional shell script? there is no way to offer an interface that fish (and other shells) could query in order to extract completions in real-time?

Comment: maybe I'm looking for the fish equivalent of this bash-helper: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argcomplete/0.6.5

Comment: please note that `argcomplete` requires you to launch a bash script to work, named `activate-global-python-argcomplete` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argcomplete/0.6.5#activating-global-completion (then, again, you have to write a shell script if you want to replicate this approach)

Comment: @furins yup, I am discovering that it's shell scripts all the way down :) your comments are pointing me in the right direction, thanks

Comment: note to self: see also https://github.com/dbarnett/python-selfcompletion and http://furius.ca/optcomplete/ for more attempts on the Python side

Comment: queries/feature requests: https://github.com/kislyuk/argcomplete/issues/68, https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1217 and https://github.com/dbarnett/python-selfcompletion/issues/2

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Adapted from [zanchey's comment on GitHub](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1217#issuecomment-31441757):

If you have a program `myprog` which takes the `--_completion` option, you can write a single completion stub for `myprog` that looks like this:

```
complete --command myprog --arguments '(myprog --_completion (commandline -cp)'
```

Your program will then get invoked as `myprog --_completion myprog some arguments here`, and you can respond with the appropriate completions. It should return only the current token that is being completed (you could also pass this to the program with `(commandline -ct)`, or tokenise it yourself), followed optionally by a tab and a short description. Multiple completions are separated with new lines.

Notes:

- `--_completion` is a convention suggested by the [python-selfcompletion](https://github.com/dbarnett/python-selfcompletion/) library, but you can use anything you want, and this answer is not Python-specific
- There is no way to specify the default completion as described in [dbarnett/python-selfcompletion#2 (GitHub comment)](https://github.com/dbarnett/python-selfcompletion/issues/2#issuecomment-31434077). You would definitely have to make a short stub for each command.

For Python scripts specifically, the following libraries may support fish completions at some point in the future (but they don't yet):

- [argcomplete](https://github.com/kislyuk/argcomplete/issues/68)
- [python-selfcompletion](https://github.com/dbarnett/python-selfcompletion/issues/2)

Comment: I have tried a similar command. It did work when I execute it in a Fish session, but it didn't work when I put it in `config.fish`.

Answer (score 15):

You should create a [fish autocomplete function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657803/creating-autocomplete-script-with-sub-commands) for your script and `source` it or put it in `~/.config/fish/completions/myprog.fish` folder.

reference: [fish docs](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/completions.html#writing-your-own-completions)

Comment: [Docs path](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/completions.html#writing-your-own-completions)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to complete the answer of @lofidevops in some edge case.

In my case I am using https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jessevdk/go-flags  which works similarly, but expect all arguments to be passed separately, not just a single one with space . `(commandline -cp)` does not return a list of argument, but a a single string with space.

In my case the following complete function worked like a charm:

```
complete -c my_prog -f  -a "(GO_FLAGS_COMPLETION=1 my_prog (string split ' ' (commandline -cp)))"
```